# Configure hibernate to process like with [] (square brackets) against maxDB and sql-server in the same way

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, wildcard, sql-like, maxdb

I have the following jpql with a LIKE

```
SELECT someField FROM someEntity WHERE otherField LIKE '%foo[bar]'
```

I want to retrieve all rows ending with 'foo[bar]'. For *maxDb* this is OK.
But for *sql-server* the square brackets are interpreted as wildcards
(usually in sql server [a-d] would match all rows containg a,b,c or d inside the brackets). I wonder why hibernate is not interpreting the String 'foo[bar]' as String and excaping the square brackets by itself.
The following hibernate dialects are used: for *maxDB hibernate.ExtSAPDBDialect* and for *sql-server org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect*.
Right now I have to differentiate in Java between my destination systems, so I can decide if to escape the brackets or not.
I wonder why I need to do this in code. Is there a possibility to teach hibernate to consider this, so I can use only the select.

Answer (score 0):

It will add additional overhead as it's one more operation and index seek can't be used, but you can replace these the `]` and `[` with something [else](https://www.ascii-code.com/). For example:

```
REPLACE(someColumn, '[', CHAR(31)) LIKE '%foo' + CHAR(30) + 'bar]'
```

or you can try using [ESCAPE](https://maxdb.sap.com/doc/7_6/8c/ccce27c71c11d2a97100a0c9449261/content.htm) option as it's supported in `maxdb`, too. In T-SQL, it will be:

```
DECLARE @someTable TABLE
(
    [someColumn] NVARCHAR(128)
);

INSERT INTO @someTable ([someColumn])
VALUES ('test foo[bar]')
      ,('test foo[bar');

SELECT * 
FROM @someTable 
WHERE someColumn LIKE '%foo|[bar]' ESCAPE '|';
```

Comment: Hello gotqn and thank you for your reply,
I changed my question, because I think it wasn´t clear, that I´m using jpql. I want hibernate to escape the '%foo[bar]' for me, so I don´t have to do it. For maxDB there is no ESCAPE needed, because I wan the String to be interpreted as is in the jpql. 
Best regards

Comment: Hi @BenjaminSchmidt , are you saying the `Answer is useful`, your Question is solved?

Comment: Hello @StefanWuebbe, the question is not solved. I don´t want to Escape the square brackets, I want hibernate to do this for me (if possible), so that I don´t have to write separate code for maxDB and sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Today I encounter same/similar issue (I know that this question is almost 2 years old). Below I will share my research outcome which ended in a working code, properly handling [ character . Maybe someone will find it useful.

Just replace single bracket [ with double one [[ with following code:

```
String preparedQuery = query.replaceAll("\\[", "\\[\\[");
List<Element> elements = repository.findByName(preparedQuery);
```

If you use `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect` it also supports mentioned by @gotqn ESCAPE operation, I tested it  as a part of HQL in `@Query` annotation. For example:

```
@Query("FROM elements WHERE name LIKE %:preparedQuery% ESCAPE '['") 
List<Element> findByName(@Param("preparedQuery") String preparedQuery);
```

I tried with different drivers/dialects without a success, so I doubt that there is an automatic solution for that (but maybe I'm wrong). With a little effort you can achieve what you want and use easily MS SQL Server / Azure SQL Server with Hibernate / HQL.